# Parsing an XML from an URL

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm pasing an XML from an URL `http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote`

and i'm creating a php, to convert BRL to USD

The Website above, show all conversions, i'm trying to get so BRL/USD

My code:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote');
$xml=simplexml_load_string($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->resources->resource as $resource) {
    echo $resource->$field;
}
```

How to get so BRL/USD?

Comment: Result: http://davidev.tk/bolsa.php

Comment: You can edit the code to place to works?

Comment: Success with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `resource` and check the field, then you can get the conversion rate.

```
file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote');
$xml=simplexml_load_string($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->resources->resource as $resource) {
    if($resource->field[0]->attributes() == 'name' && $resource->field[0] == 'USD/BRL') {
        echo $resource->field[1];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use a different API that allows query for your two rates.

```
$da_json = file_get_contents('http://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=BRL');
$json = json_decode($da_json, TRUE);
echo $json['rate'];
```